# Is index.html name is predefined in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHHDy.jpg)  [login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCSRv.jpg)  [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJLkM.jpg)
I have two files named index.html & login.html,whenever I start server with index.html file it load ,but when I route to the login then login.html don't work,so then after I interchange code in files then login.html files **load but as index.html**

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about

Comment: How to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it works, not much information is provided in the question.
Maybe show your code.

```
var express = require('express');
var PORT = 3400;
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
   req.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));

})

app.get('/index',function(req,res){
   req.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));

});

app.listen(PORT,function(){
   console.log('Serving on PORT' + PORT);
})
```